# Can we implement google play game services Multiplayer games with Facebook and not just Google+?

Tags: facebook, google-play-services

Basically, I want to make Multiplayer games but found Google Play Game Services only works with Google+ Login: 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

How does one implement this with Facebook login so people can play with their facebook friends, etc.

Comment: They would have to login to both Google Play Game Services *and* Facebook.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an option where it was a bit easier than that. Like have a button where you login with google+ but dont have to be asked to login to facebook. Just that there will be a button in the menu where if u do decide to invite facebook friend for a game, u can do so.

Comment: I am guessing this can be implemented in objective-C if you had to go that route but I was hoping for a better solution.